# Dynamically changing row font color in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a database table named weather which has the following data as below :

```
Place       Temperature

Delhi          30
Bangalore      35
Hyderabad      45
Mumbai         41
```

Now I fetch these data using php and view them to the client in a table.

Now my question how can I dynamically change row font color based on value i.e the temperature.
Shall I have to put the function in server side or in client side using javascript.

I have applied the logic in this manner but have not reached the destination.

```
//here is my logic that i have put in my php file while fetching the data
if (row["Temperature"] > row["MaxTemperature"]){
    this.getStyle().color= "red"; }
    else{
    this.getStyle().color="yellow";}
   //I have set a value for MaximumTemperate
```

Comment: Why have you put what appears to be JavaScript in your PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this by creating several css classes, ie:

```
<style>
.red_temperature {
color: red;
}

.yellow_temperature {
color:yellow;
}
</style>
```

then in your php, when you generate your client-side code, you add the class to the class="" of the div holding the values you're displaying to the client.

ie:

```
<?php
// set $classColor variable here based on mysql row
...

echo "<div class='".$classColor."'>74</div>"; // where $classColor = 'yellow_temperature'
?>
```

This is meant to be a generic starting point, not final code, but just trying to point you in the right direction with the right frame of thinking.

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://webplums.com/temp/demo_23558324/)

common.php

```
<?php

$ArrayList[0] = array('place'=>'Delhi','temperature'=>30);
$ArrayList[1] = array('place'=>'Bangalore','temperature'=>35);
$ArrayList[2] = array('place'=>'Hyderabad','temperature'=>45);
$ArrayList[3] = array('place'=>'Mumbai','temperature'=>41);

$MaxTemperature = 40;

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('common.php');

$Content = '
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Place</td>`
<td>Temperature</td>
</tr>
';
foreach ($ArrayList as $k=>$v)
{
$place = $v['place'];
$temperature =  $v['temperature'];

$temperature_color = ($temperature >= $MaxTemperature) ? 'color:red;' : 'color:black;';

$Content .= '
<tr>
<td>'.$place.'</td>
<td style="'.$temperature_color.'">'.$temperature.'</td>
</tr>
';  
}

$Content .= '</table>';

echo $Content;
?>
```

If you are looking for the same, let me know, Ill upload the files

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$Color = "Color:yellow;";
if (Temp>MaxTemp)
{
    $Color="Color:red;";
}
?>

<div style='<?php echo $Color ?>'>TempValue</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this, please correct me if i wrong

```
if ($row['temperature'] > $row['max_temperature'])
{
echo "<font color='red'> red</font>";
}
else { echo" <font color='yellow'>yellow</font>";
}
```

Comment: Since [the color attribute of `font` is not supported in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp), OP should rather use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friends How Is It Set The Color For Work Status ,Project Name And Module Name

```
$items[]=array(
             'title'=>""."Work Status:".$status."\n".'Emp Name  : '.$Emp->employee_name."[".$position."]"."\n".'Project Name : '.$project->project_name."\n".'Module Name : '.$module->module_name."",

            'start'=>$value->start_date,
            'end'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($value->end_date))),
            'color'=>'#006699',
```